# Android.Net not being recognized for placing phone calls for Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Android.Net has a error and it says "

> The type or namespace name "Net" does not exist in the namespace
>   "TourStops.Android".

I marked where this happened.  I have looked at other tutorials that have it this way and I tried alternatives that didn't work.  I am guessing it has something to do with the namespace TourStops.Android because of the .Android.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace TourStops.Android
{
[Activity(Label = "TourStops.Android", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.callButton1);
        Button button2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.callButton2);

        button1.Click += delegate
        {
            CallNumber(button1.Text);
        };

        button2.Click += delegate
        {
            CallNumber(button2.Text);
        };
    }
        private void CallNumber(string phoneNumber)
    {
        var callDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        callDialog.SetMessage("Call" + phoneNumber);

        callDialog.SetPositiveButton("Call ", delegate { });//yes button
        var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
//Android.Net has a error and it says the type or namespace name "Net" does not exist in the namespace 
        callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
        StartActivity(callIntent);

        callDialog.SetPositiveButton("Call", delegate { });//yes button
        callDialog.SetNeutralButton("Cancel ", delegate { });//cancel button
        callDialog.Show();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `global::` prefix will fix your compiler error since your local app namespace is overlapping with a global one.

#### Example:

```
var foobar = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:555-1212");
```

> `global::` The ability to access a member in the global namespace is useful when the member might be hidden by another entity of the same name.

[Use the Global Namespace Alias (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx)

Comment: I thought the highest level was the namespace.  How does that work with this?  Does the .Android make it a lower level because the namespace TourStops by itself is the higher level?

Comment: prefixing with global will cause the search for the identifier to the right of it at to begin with the global namespace, otherwise the local namespace rules the search. The MSDN article walks through the different issues from clashing with classes vs namespaces that are the same to the namespace search order.

Comment: @DDJ You can also use `using MyNet = Android.Net;` to provide a different namespace qualifier and then code it as: `var foobar2 = MyNet.Uri.Parse("tel:555-1212");`